# Pygame - Key UP / DOWN behaviour

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I am trying to understand a "weird" pygame behaviour by using the KEY DOWN and UP.
I keep "up arrow" pressed down all the time but I get events from KEY UP...

Below you can see my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import speed

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))

lastKey = 'z'

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed.Forward()
                lastKey = 'f'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed.Backward()
                lastKey = 'b'
            else:
                lastKey = 'z'
                pass

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if lastKey != 'z':
                speed.Stop()
```

Here are the results:

pressed "up arrow" down...

```
Forward
Stop
Forward
Stop
Forward
Stop
Forward
Stop
```

released the "up arrow"

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If You Have a Problem With This:**
Your problem lays in the string in the variable `lastKey`. I have modified your code for debugging, so instead of the speed functions and importing the `speed` module, I simply made it print something. For your `pygame.KEYUP` event, I made it do `print lastKey`. Here is the modified code:

```
import pygame
import sys


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))

lastKey = 'z'

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                print 'Forward'
                lastKey = 'f'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                print 'Backward'
                lastKey = 'b'
            else:
                lastKey = 'z'
                pass

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if lastKey == 'z':
                print 'Stopped'
                print lastKey
```

When the results were shown, I have found that your error was in the `else` part. When you do that piece of code, that code only activates when the user presses any other key than `K_UP` and `K_DOWN`. So, it never really reset your variable back to `z`. I figured that you wanted when `lastKey` is equal to `z`, do `speed.Stop()` (in your case), I changed the last `if` line to:

```
if lastKey == 'z':
```

Now, to prevent the weird behavior (you must change the last if statement to the above one to be able to work), add this line before that `if` statement:

```
lastKey = 'z'
```

This will make tell the program that the no keys are being pressed, preventing the behavior. Also, your `else` statement is not need so I would remove it. For your final code, it should be:

```
import pygame
import sys
import speed

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1))

lastKey = 'z'

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed.Forward()
                lastKey = 'f'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed.Backward()
                lastKey = 'b'

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            lastKey == 'z'
            if lastKey == 'z':
                speed.Stop()
```

This should fix your problem by only allowing the `KEYUP` event only activate when you lift the key. I hope this helps you!
**If You Want to Know Its Behaviour:**
Your results are natural. The variable is always either `f` or `b` so the KEYUP events are activated since the strings aren't `x`.